# Is $\mathbb{C}[Q_8]$ semiprime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Maschke Theorem**: Let $G$ be a finite group. Then the group algebra $F[G]$ is semiprime if and only if either $char(F) = 0$ or $char(F)$ is a prime number $p$ that does not divide $|G|$.

> 1:According to this  theorem,  **Is $\mathbb{C}[Q_8]$ semiprime?**
>
> 2: According to what kind of theorem , we can say that $\mathbb{C}[Q_8]$ is a semisimple algebra?

**Wedderburn Theorem:** Let $A$ be a nonzero finite dimensional algebra. Then
$A$ is semiprime if and only if there exist $n_1, . . . ,n_r \in \mathbb{N}$  and division algebras $D_1, . . . ,D_r$ such that $A \cong M_{n_{1}}(D_1) \times....... \times M_{n_{r}}(D_r)$

> 3: If the first question is correct , and using the theorem Wedderburn , can I   show
> $ \mathbb{C} [ Q_8] \cong M_{2}(\mathbb{C}) \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} $?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the dimension of the center of A) $\Bbb{C}[Q_8]$, B) $M_{n_i}(\Bbb{C})$?

Comment: Do you mean " $| Q_8 | = 8$then $ \sum n_i = 8 $"?

Comment: The center of $\mathbb{C} [ Q_8]$and $M_{n_{1}}(\mathbb{C})$? What do you mean?

Comment: We had this already at MSE. So far I found it [here](https://www.queryoverflow.gdn/query/the-wedderburn-decomposition-21_2583327.html).

Comment: The center of $\Bbb{C}[G]$ is spanned by the formal sums of conjugacy classes of $G$. $Q_8$ has five conjugacy classes, Ergo, the center of $\Bbb{C}[Q_8]$ is five dimensional. The center of $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ is 1-dimensional (=the scalar matrices). Therefore the Wedderburn decomposition has five summands. The dimension of $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ is $n^2$. The only way to write $8$ as a sum of five squares is $4+1+1+1+1$. Done.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think we should make that a solution.

Comment: @Jak Have some faith in yourself! I don't believe you have any doubt that $\mathbb C$ has characteristic $0$, and therefore Machke's theorem applies, so asking about $1$ is pointless. Actually, the only version of Maschke's theorem I've ever heard concludes "$F[G]$ is semisimple" not semiprime... but we'll go with your version. It doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Mathphile: Please do not blindly add tags without reading the question and tag description to see if they are relevant.